# Why is angular not clearing my filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown that is setting a search model object to be used in an ng-repeat filter.

```
<select ng-model="search.location_id" ng-options="id as name for (id,name) in search_locations">
    <option value="">Location</option>
</select>
```

I also have my default value 'Location' meant to clear the search. The problem is that when I select a location (which filters my list correctly), then go back to the default 'Location' option, it clears all my ng-repeat items instead of clearing the search filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:search">
```

The course objects obviously have course.location_id properties. The 'search_locations' is a list of locations to search by of form { id:name , id:name }

How do I get my full list back? / Clear this specific search param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When angular runs a filter and the value is **undefined** then the filter short circuits and the whole list is returned (this was the same behaviour if the filter value was **null** prior to angular 1.2)

What you can do is add an extra object to the search_locations array with the location_id set to undefined:

```
$scope.search_locations = [
    { description: 'show all', location_id: undefined },
    { description: 'block 1', location_id: 1 },
    { description: 'block 2', location_id: 2 }
];
```

Demo **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/U3pVM/2973/)**.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the value assigned to `search.location_id` when the default option is selected is `null` and if `search.location_id === null`, then nothing in your `courses` list will match (unless, of course `course.location_id === null`).

The example on the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) show that the default value is `null`.

Example of what is selected when the value being searched for is `null`: http://plnkr.co/edit/meKe7l6rubaHEN1eRbzC?p=preview

**Template**:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
        Id: {{item.id}}, Name: {{item.name}}
     </p>
 </body>
```

**Controller**:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'alice'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: null
  }];

  $scope.search = {
    name: null
  };
});
```

Will output only the second item in the `items` list.

To address this issue, write your own `filter` function.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I still don't know how to get my whole ng-repeat list back. I feel like this should be a common thing.

Comment: @snowman4415 This is a [long](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1780) [standing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5117) [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5055) with Angular and they have decided to make `null` match only `null` instead of acting like a `falsey` value. You can write your own function to filter the array in your custom way **or** use `ng-repeat` to create the `option` you want since you are using only `string` as `values` for the `model` and not objects.